# Cannot create a NEW PROJECT in GCP, Permission issue with location

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Cannot create a NEW GCP Project.It asks for a location and attempt to select my organization a Hazard error appears. "You do not have permission to create projects in this location"

Screen Shot: http://prntscr.com/mdkbkz

I am Google Apps User. 
Verified valid billing account

Comment: what kind of google product are you trying to use ?

Comment: Login to the GCP Console. Go to IAM & admin -> IAM. Do your have `Owner` role? Of you do not, contact the account owner.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the response.  I just got off support with Google, and figured out the issue. Yes it was a permissions issue and apparently you need the following roles: Organization Role Administrator & Project Creator.  Thanks again!

Comment: The minimum roles to create a project in an organization or in a folder is Project Creator. To actually use the new account you also need Billing Account User so that you can setup billing for the new project.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you need the following roles: Organization Role Administrator & Project Creator.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permission on that organization that's why you cannot create project. Kindly check the Organization Admin about your permission.